# Feed forward neural networks for the analysis of censored survival data, how should I implement it in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, survival, neural-networks

Recently, I have read an article which name is “[*Feed forward neural networks for the analysis of censored survival data: A partial logistic regression approach*](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9618776)”.

Without a math background, I catch only a little about the ANN applying the analysis of censored survival data.

In the training group, each subject is replicated for all the intervals in which the subjects is observed and coupled with the event; why is this done? Especially, in the testing group, indicator each subjects are replicated into full number of time interval of observed with all event indicator as zero?

I know this process can take into account the censoring data.

In addition, are the output of neural networks are conditional probabilities of failure? My problem is how to produce the survival curve using the output data. Does anybody know the R code or MATLAB code to perform this whole process? Or give me some suggestion to find answers! The following R code is my try on this method but I can't go on it, for I don't know draw the survival curve depending on the output conditional failure probabilities!

```
dat<-read.csv("traininglj.csv",header=T)
tt <- dat$time <- as.numeric(cut(dat$TTR,c(0,6,12,18,24,30,36,42,48,54,200)))
dat2 <- dat[rep(1:nrow(dat), tt), ]
time2 <- NULL
for (i in 1:length(tt)) time2 <- c(time2, 1:tt[i])
dat2$time <- time2
    dat2$Recurrence <- 0
dat2$Recurrence[cumsum(tt)] <- dat$Recurrence
write.csv(dat2,file="result.csv")
mydat <- apply(dat2[,13:23],2,function(x)(x-min(x,na.rm=TRUE))/
    (range(x,na.rm=TRUE)[2]-range(x,na.rm=TRUE)[1]))
training <- cbind(dat2[,1:12],mydat,dat2[24])
library(nnet)
library(lattice)
attach(training)
dat.net <- nnet(Recurrence ~ time+ALT+ALB+PLT+INR+age+MELD+logAFP+Diameter
        +sex+number+Gstage+HBsAg+AN+MVI, 
    data = training, 
    size = 12, 
    decay=0.025,
    maxit = 1000,
    entropy=TRUE,
    trace=TRUE)
```

Comment: Not sure if this site is the right platform for such a question. You would perhaps have more luck if you explained what you are trying to achieve and asked for some pointers to standard methods instead of trying to implement a new technique from scratch, an endeavor fraught with difficulty even when you do understand the technique.